# Shadow maps : sampling on the same UVs

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader, shadow, shadow-mapping

I have a problem using shadow maps in OpenGL when 2 pixels from the camera view are on the same UVs on the shadow map. Here's how this looks like :

[shadow map on the same UVs problem http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/4459/ida9.png](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/4459/ida9.png)

Both visible shadows appears on the shadow map in the same UVs, obviously the shadow on the side is the problem. Is there a way to fix this ?

Here's my fragment shader :

```
float get_shadow(vec4 _shadow_coords, sampler2D _sampler){
    if(_shadow_coords.w <= 0.0) return 1.0;
    float uu = ((_shadow_coords.x / _shadow_coords.w) * 0.5) + 0.5;
    float vv = ((_shadow_coords.y / _shadow_coords.w) * 0.5) + 0.5;
    if(uu <= 0.0) return 1.0;
    if(uu > 1.0) return 1.0;
    if(vv <= 0.0) return 1.0;
    if(vv > 1.0) return 1.0;
    float zz = 0.0, zzz = 0.0;
    zz = unpack(_sampler, vec2(uu, vv));
    zzz = _shadow_coords.z / _shadow_coords.w;
    if(zz < zzz - 0.005) return min_diff;
    return 1.0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are "_shadow_coords"? Is that the position of something?

Comment: shadow_coords = light_source_matrix * vertex_position